# A fair coin is tossed until both heads and tails apear

Tags: probability, random-variables

A fair coin is tossed until both heads and tails have been obtained. Let x = the number of tosses needed (for example, if the sequence of tosses is HHT, then x = 3; If the sequence is TTTTTH, then x = 6).

Find the expected value of x aka E(x).

I think E(x) = 1/P, where P is the probability of getting a heads or tails.

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: Look at the definition of the expectation. $E(x) = (0 \times \text{probability of stopping after 0 tosses}) + (1 \times \text{probability of stopping after 1 tosses}) + \ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the result of the first toss is, say tail, we have used up one toss, and are waiting for head to show up.

The waiting time **after** the first toss has **geometric** distribution, with mean $\frac{1}{1/2}=2$.

So the expected waiting time until each of head and tail has shown up is $3$.